# creat 2 different pop up menu in android

Tags: android, popupmenu

my sign_up.xml file is:

```
public class sign_upActivity extends Activity implements AlertPositiveListener{

private RadioGroup radioGenderGroup,radioEduGroup;
private RadioButton radioGenderButton,radioEduButton;
int position = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gender_btn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.06"
            android:background="@drawable/arraw_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
             android:id="@+id/education_btn"
             android:layout_width="30dp"
             android:layout_height="34dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.06"
             android:background="@drawable/arraw_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/education_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have two button. when click in one of them, a pop up menu appear and ask the user select on of the radio buttons and click OK. when click on the other button, another pop up menu appear and have another buttons.my activity is:

```
 OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
            Bundle b  = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", position);
            alert.setArguments(b);
            alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");

        }
    }; 
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gender_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

@Override
public void onPositiveClick(int position) {

        this.position = position;
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender_tv);
        tv.setText(Gender.code[this.position]); 
}
```

}

and AlertDialogRadio is:

```
public class AlertDialogRadio  extends DialogFragment{


/** Declaring the interface, to invoke a callback function in the implementing activity class */
AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener;


/** An interface to be implemented in the hosting activity for "OK" button click listener */
interface AlertPositiveListener {
    public void onPositiveClick(int position);

    void onPositiveClick(int position, int type);
}


/** This is a callback method executed when this fragment is attached to an activity. 
 *  This function ensures that, the hosting activity implements the interface AlertPositiveListener 
 * */
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        alertPositiveListener = (AlertPositiveListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        // The hosting activity does not implemented the interface AlertPositiveListener
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AlertPositiveListener");
    }
}


/** This is the OK button listener for the alert dialog, 
 *  which in turn invokes the method onPositiveClick(position) 
 *  of the hosting activity which is supposed to implement it
 */ 
OnClickListener positiveListener = new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog)dialog;
        int position = alert.getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();            
        alertPositiveListener.onPositiveClick(position);            
    }
};

/** This is a callback method which will be executed 
 *  on creating this fragment
 */
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Getting the arguments passed to this fragment */
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();     
    int position = bundle.getInt("position");


    /** Creating a builder for the alert dialog window */
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


    /** Setting a title for the window */
    b.setTitle("Choose your version");      


    /** Setting items to the alert dialog */
    b.setSingleChoiceItems(Gender.code, position, null);


    /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
    b.setPositiveButton("OK",positiveListener);

    /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);


    /** Creating the alert dialog window using the builder class */
    AlertDialog d = b.create();

    /** Return the alert dialog window */
    return d;
}
```

}

but i can only implement one of the pop up menus. any one help me?